# Remove double quotes from add to cart message in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to find out how to remove or replace the double quotes from the WooCommerce add to cart message.

> “UNF #10 x 1/4″” has been added to your CART.

[Here is my Notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8tk6.png)

I am dealing with some Imperial Measurements, and the double quotes look untidy surrounding the " for inch in the Product Name.

I have added filters at every stage of the message display

- my last attempt is shown below
- but I've also tried

`add_filter ( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html_filter', 10, 2 );`

I have tried the find string

- as "“"
- and escaped "\“"
- and as Unicode

I can replace *any other* part of the message.

But I can't remove or replace those pesky quotes.

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_add_success', 'woocommerce_add_success_filter', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_add_success_filter ( $message ) {

    $message = str_replace("basket","CART", $message);
    $message = str_replace("\“","[ ", $message);

    return $message;
}
```

Any help or clues?

Comment: They probably aren't `"` quotation marks. They may be `“` and `”` marks ... the kind that word processing software helpfully puts in for you around quotations when you write text.

Comment: Yup. Indeed. I had worked that out but to no avail. They are respectively: U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK -and- U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK.

Comment: It helps a lot to hit https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html and then use your browser's ctrl-f search to look for what you need.

Comment: @O.Jones : Thanks. Useful. Bookmarked. That saves me a lot of 'forensic digging'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_item_name_in_quotes` hook to remove double quotes from the added to cart messages.

Replace this part

```
_x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' )
```

With

```
_x( '%s', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' )
```

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_item_name_in_quotes( $item_name, $product_id ) {
    // Item name 
    $item_name = sprintf( _x( '%s', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) );
    
    return $item_name;
}
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_item_name_in_quotes', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_item_name_in_quotes', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Aww man ... I'd buy you a beer if you were anywhere near Cape Town. I knew the quotes were lying deeper than I was digging. Still too much of a Wordpress newbie to have worked out for myself quite where that was.

Comment: And I added this line in to replace the quotes with square brackets which look a lot neater for my purposes.

`$item_name = "[ " . $item_name . " ]";`

Gives me:  **[ Product Item ]**